# lithium, lipo and lithium-ion tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup

We have two tags, [lithium](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lithium) and [lipo](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lipo). Now an edit to the first suggests that lithium batteries are disposable and non-rechargeable batteries, unlike LiPo ones. It seems a valid argument to have separate tags, but all the questions with that tag are about LiPo batteries.

We also have a [lithium-ion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lithium-ion) tag, which again could have the same meaning of [lipo](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lipo). Should we merge all of them or keep [lithium](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lithium) separated?

Comment: create better tags like `lithium-battery` and `lithium-ion-battery` then? and add a tag wiki to explain which is which?

Comment: @endolith - not sure it makes much difference. Obviously it's about batteries, and not anti-depressants, but `lithium-battery` still doesn't indicate that they're non-rechargeable.

Comment: @stevenvh: that's what the tag wiki is for. Doesn't it pop up while you're choosing which tag to use?

Answer (score 1):

A lithium coin cell and a Li-Ion battery (such as Li-Poly) are two separate things and should not be tagged the same.

But it's hard for me to care much, since tags are so poorly deployed on this site.

Comment: *But it's hard for me to care much, since tags are so poorly deployed on this site.* Exactly! +1

Comment: @Olin and markrages - No offense, but it won't change if everybody feels that way about it.

Comment: @stevenvh yup..

Comment: @stevenvh: Tags are below the critical mass threshold here.  They are done poorly and the interface is difficult, so people ignore them.  Since people ignore them, they don't care.  So they continue to be done poorly and with a difficult interface.  Since a real fix is unlikely to happen, I don't consider it worth my time to address the issue.

Comment: @OlinLathrop and Mark, I agree, they are poorly done, but it disheartens me to see people say, why try to improve it. If you have no interest in making it better dont vote on the discussions for other saying, "Who cares", instead lets try to fix it. It also is sad to see a diamond mod saying that they dont care to improve things...

Comment: Tags are poor by design.  According to Jeff in the stackexchange podcast, tags are designed as busywork for bored power users so they don't resort to trolling.

Comment: Mods are janitors.  Janitors do an important job, but taking out the trash doesn't set the direction of the company.